# How to optimize uWSGI python app + nginx on Ubuntu?

Tags: python, ubuntu, nginx, uwsgi

I have a simple Flask application that exposes one api. Calling the api runs a python algorithm that does a lot of string manipulation and file reading (no writing). The algorithm takes about 1000ms. I'm trying to see if there's anyway to optimize concurrent requests. I'm running on a single instance of 4 vCPU VM.

I wrote a client that makes a request every 1000ms. There's minimal RAM usage, and CPU usage is about 35%. When I up the request to every 750ms. RAM usage did not increase by much, but CPU usage doubles to 70%. If I increase the requests to every 500ms, the response will start taking longer time, eventually timing out. CPU usage is at 100%, and RAM is still minimal.

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04) to set my application. I enabled threads in my uWSGI settings. However, I did not really notice much difference.

I was hoping to get some advice on what I can do software/settings-wise to respond better to concurrent requests.

Comment: sorry. I meant one request per 750ms, so about 1.33 request/second

Comment: Sorry I also mistyped my comment (deleted) I meant the same thing you did :-) 1.33 per second. But that's per core isn't it? YOur server is able to serve approximately 4 requests per second overall?

Comment: 1.33 per second all together. I don't think it can server 4 requests a second. When trying to make 2 requests a second, some requests would eventually time out.
I'm not entirely sure exactly how the resources are divided up. But I do see multiple instances of uwsgi, and 100% overall CPU usage.